# Bash: how to test stdout of a ping without using any file

Tags: bash, ping

I want to retrieve all connected hosts with a script:

```
for i in {1..9}
do 
    ping -c 1 -w 1 8.8.8.$i | grep ' 0%'
done
```

So i want to add a condition using **if**, which would test if the output of each **ping** (with the piped **grep**) is empty or not, if it's not empty then host is up.

Cheers

p.s: i would like to avoid the use of a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the status of the ping command:

```
for i in {1..9}
do 
    if ping -c 1 -w 1 8.8.8.$i >/dev/null; then 
        echo "$i alive"; 
    else 
        echo "$i dead"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ping` return code to determine the status of the machine.

```
for i in {1..9}
do
    ping_status=$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.$i &> /dev/null && echo success || echo fail)

    if [ $ping_status = success ]
    then echo 'machine is up and running'
    else
       echo 'machine is down'
    fi
done
```

Comment: I like this answer but are you sure about `&>`? If yes, what does it mean?

Comment: @Inian I tried your code , i get the error: [fail : command not found

Comment: With `&>` I am suppressing all the `stdout` and `stderr` messages to a null handle, since I am worried only about the return code of the `ping` command

Comment: @aurelien75000: Works just fine for me! Which shell are you on?

Answer (score 0):

[How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)

```
for i in {1..9}
do
    out="$(ping -c 1 -w 1 8.8.8.$i | grep ' 0%')"
    if [ -z "$out" ]; then
        # output empty
    fi
done
```

Comment: Try `if test -z "$out"; then` instead.

Comment: @aurelien75000 You need a space beetween [ and -z

Answer (score 0):

You could use glob matching within a case/esac. This avoids an expensive fork to `grep`.

```
for i in {1..9}; do
   case $(ping -c 1 8.8.8.$i) in
   (*" 0%"*)
      echo something
   ;;
   (*)
      echo something else
   ;;
   esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it faster in parallel with `GNU Parallel` like this:

```
parallel -j 64 -k 'ip=8.8.8.{}; ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo $ip' ::: {1..254}
```

Or you can use `nmap` like this:

```
nmap -sP 8.8.8.* | tr -d "()" | awk '/Nmap scan report/{h=$NF} /Host is up/{print h}'
```